# Generate R lookup table based on functional parameters

Tags: r, dataframe, simulation, lookup

I'm running an individual-based simulation in which each individual is governed by a stochastic variable `mort_rate`. `N` number of `mort_rate` may be randomized as a function of 2 parameters: `mort_distr(N, parm1, parm2)`. Here, for the purpose of illustration,

```
mort_distr <- function(N, parm1, parm2)

{
  v    <- rnorm(n=N, mean=parm1)
  mort <- v * exp(1./parm2)

  data.frame(id=1:N,
             mort=mort,
             parm1=parm1,
             parm2=parm2)
}
```

So,

```
> mort_distr(N=3, parm1=2., parm2=10.)
  id     mort parm1 parm2
1  1 1.908670     2    10
2  2 5.351502     2    10
3  3 2.440259     2    10
```

My question is: in order to cut down computational time, how do I pre-generate a 3D look-up table in R that includes `N=500` samples of `mort_rate` for each combination of `parm1` and `parm2`, varying from `seq(0.,4.,0.2)` and `seq(5.,10.,1.)`, respectively? In other words, I wish to have a table `mort_tab` that allows me to rapidly sample `mort_rate` based on known parameters simply by running, e.g. `mort_tab(1.,9.)`

Comment: Sounds like you could just use `outer(seq(0.,4.,0.2), seq(5.,10.,1.), mort_distr)`. It would be helpful to have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @G5W I think they're asking for 500 samples per pair of parameters since `mort_rate` is stochastic.

Comment: @Lyngbark You are correct.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for the helpful suggestion. I've now edited my question to include a reproducible example.